# Why isnt plt.show() working with plt.plot? (when showing model training and testing results)

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras

I have trained a CNN model and am trying to display the results. However, despite the below code having no errors (it is the chunk of my code where I display the graph with matplotlib), no graph shows. I have looked at numerous tutorials yet none seem to help

Here is the code:

```
def plot_accuracies(history):
    """ Plot the history of accuracies"""
    accuracies = [x['val_acc'] for x in history]
    plt.plot(accuracies, '-x')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.title('Accuracy vs. No. of epochs');


plot_accuracies(history)


def plot_losses(history):
    """ Plot the losses in each epoch"""
    train_losses = [x.get('train_loss') for x in history]
    val_losses = [x['val_loss'] for x in history]
    plt.plot(train_losses, '-bx')
    plt.plot(val_losses, '-rx')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.legend(['Training', 'Validation'])
    plt.title('Loss vs. No. of epochs');


plot_losses(history)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

For more control when manipulating figures with pyplot, it is usefull to explicitely define the objects instead of letting pyplot dealing with them in the background. I suggest you try defining you ax and figure objects globaly and then add the different plots before showing. Something like this:

```
def plot_losses(history):
    """ Plot the losses in each epoch"""
    train_losses = [x.get('train_loss') for x in history]
    val_losses = [x['val_loss'] for x in history]
    ax.plot(train_losses, '-bx') # plot the same way but in the ax object
    ax.plot(val_losses, '-rx')
    ax.set_xlabel('epoch') # when using ax, most method get "set_"
    ax.set_ylabel('loss')
    ax.legend(['Training', 'Validation'])
    ax.set_title('Loss vs. No. of epochs');

fig,ax = plt.subplots() # define the objects

plot_losses(history)

fig.savefig("losses.pdf") # save figure locally
fig.show() # show figure
```

You can do the same for the other function. Name the `ax` and `fig` objects differently if you want to define keep both plots at the same time.